# Can not run angular2 in commonjs way

Tags: typescript, angular, gulp, commonjs

First, I don't know the difference between `@angular` and `angular2` in package.json.
But I like angular2 way in package.json.
Here is my [github source](https://github.com/JeffreyChan/angular2-seed).

The problem is that I can't change "system" to "commonjs" in tsconfig_c.json, otherwise angular2 will throw error that I can't understand.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- #docregion head -->
<!-- #docregion base-href -->

<head>
  <base href="/" />
  <!-- #enddocregion base-href -->
  <title>Angular 2 Seed</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <!-- #docregion css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <!-- #enddocregion css -->

  <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
  <script src="libs/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/Rx.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/angular2.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/router.dev.js"></script>

  <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
  <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/bootstrap')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->

<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

**Config:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

If compile the "system" way, all is good. But I prefer the "commonjs" way.
Anyone could help me fix this?

Comment: When angular2 was in beta it used to represent packages using angular2 and when Angular2 moved into release candidate (RC) version they renamed packages as @angular. If you are starting with new project then I would suggest you to use latest angular2 version (2.0.0-rc.4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @Sanket, the `angular2` package is the old beta version of Angular 2. About your question, if you compile in `commonjs`, you must tell SystemJs that your app is in `commonjs`, so you have to change in `index.html` the configuration:

```
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'cjs', // commonjs
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: thanks very much, about format:'cjs', is any site tell about it? I want to know more.

Comment: Yes, for more information, you can see the official documentation of SystemJs: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md